# How to stop multiple records returned on reverse node reference Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-views-relationship, nodereference

I am using the 'references' module and the 'views' module (D7). I have two custom content types - 'Universities' and 'Courses'. The Universities content type has a custom field (field_courses) which references university courses' nodes and can have multiple nodes attached.

I have created Universities 'Harvard' and 'Yale' and created a course called 'Animation'

I have attached the Animation course to both Yale and Harvard.

I have created a view '/courses' and added the relationship: 'Content: Courses (field_courses) - reverse' and have also added '(field_courses) Content: Title (Uni)' in the fields section.

This creates my view.

The problem with the view is that it is returning two animation records (one for each uni) but I only want one record (with the uni's returned as an array within the single record.

For example the data I am getting back is:

```
course: Animation
Nid: 1239
description: Animation course
Uni: Harvard

course: Animation
Nid: 1239
description:Animation course
Uni: Yale
```

I would like it to be:

```
course: Animation
Nid: 1239
description: Animation course
Uni: Harvard, Yale
```

Is it possible to change this in this views module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) module will do what you require

Answer (score 0):

Checking the "Distinct" checkbox in your views "Query settings" under the Advanced tab will resolve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It states "If there are multiple identical items, each will be displayed only once." Our items are not strictly identical due to the differences in the Uni Title which need to be merged. Anyway, this didn't work. Appreciate the tip though. Thanks.

Comment: @el_nariz Views is just an SQL builder - if you can show how your requisite data structure is possible using a single SQL statement, you can make it work in Views. Otherwise you'll have to either implement it yourself, or get into the realms of writing custom field handlers

Comment: In fact, chances are you're looking for a `GROUP_CONTACT`. Views doesn't support this natively but you can implement `hook_views_query_alter()` to add it in manually

Comment: Yes, you can have a try using views aggregation settings. It provides the GROUPing features of field in views.

Comment: Tried the aggregation settings and it looks like all my fields are already set to be grouped. I think I've exhausted every option in the admin section - looks like I will need to extend views programatically. Thanks for all the help.